# Visual Studio path to namespace / function to send it by email to collegue

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Is there an easy option to get the full path to a function so I can send this to a collegue?

Desired output: 
based on paths
MySolution/Business/Accounting/Models/User.cs:25

or based on namespaces
MyBaseAssembly.Business.Accounting.Models.User (line 25)

Comment: Are you using version control?

Comment: yes, git through the embedded Team Explorer